# POST on MYSQL database done in terminal but nothing in my base

Tags: python, mysql

I would like to know why all seems to be okay but nothing is insert in my mysql database ?
I get some data from an api and I would like to insert data in table.

Using flask, python, pymysql

Thanks in advance

```
api = Flask(__name__)


def connect():
    db = pymysql.connect(database='rtap',port=3306, host='127.0.0.1', user='root', password='',ssl_ca="{ca-cert filename}", ssl_disabled=True)
    log.basicConfig(level=log.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s:\n%(message)s\n')              
    print("Connexion réussie")
    return db

@api.route('/')
def base():
    return jsonify({"version":"1.0"})

@api.route('/azure', methods=['GET'])
def read():
    db = connect()
    log.info('Reading Datas')
    plane = "SELECT * FROM `plane`;"
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(plane)
    output = cursor.fetchall()
    return jsonify(output)


@api.route('/azure', methods=['POST'])
def write():
    db = connect()
    cursor = db.cursor()
    req = request.json["response"]
    # cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO `plane` (aircraft_icao, reg_number) VALUES (%s, %s);", req)
    # print(req)
    key = []
    for i in req:
        try:
            if (key==[]) :
                plane = "INSERT INTO `plane` (aircraft_icao, reg_number) VALUES ('{}', '{}')".format(i["aircraft_icao"], i["reg_number"])
                key.append(i["reg_number"])
            else:
                if(i["reg_number"] not in key) : #si la key n'a pas encore été utilisée, on peut ecrire la requette, sinon on ne fait rien
                    plane+= ", ('{}', '{}')".format(i["aircraft_icao"], i["reg_number"])
                    key.append(i["reg_number"])
        except Exception as e:
             print("failed")
    # print(plane)
    cursor.execute(plane)
    return jsonify(req)

if __name__=='__main__':
    api.run(debug=True, port=5000, host='0.0.0.0')
```

[traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ew9Qh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the `INSERT` statement looked good at that debugging `print` function, then you probably need to commit the material to the DB after `INSERT`.  Try adding

```py
    db.commit()
    cursor.close()
```

after `cursor.execute()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to commit your table changes by doing

```
db.commit()
```

immediately after each INSERT or sequence of INSERTs. [Read this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-commit.html#:%7E:text=3%20MySQLConnection.-,commit()%20Method,that%20use%20transactional%20storage%20engines.).